# how to know if cassandra autocompaction is enabled or not

Tags: cassandra

Autocompactions can be enabled or disabled using nodetool enableautocompaction and disableautocompaction. But is there any way to know the status? I do not see any nodetool command which will show the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism to tell short of taking a heap dump currently. Best option is just to use `nodetool enableautocompaction` if you want it on regardless to be safe or setting alerting on compaction pending tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for one of the below commands:

1.[CompactionHistory](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCompactionHistory.html)

> Description: Provides the history of compaction operations.

2. [CompactionStats](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCompactionStats.html)

> Provide statistics about a compaction. The total column shows the total number of uncompressed bytes of SSTables being compacted. The system log lists the names of the SSTables compacted.

Comment: No, compaction history provides history of compactions and stats provide what is currently running in the compaction queue. What I am looking is how do I know if on a cluster if the compactions are enabled or disabled. How do I know if on a certain node, they are enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested Chris, nodetool compactionstats will probably help if autocompaction enabled then you can see some running task and pending task may be 0 or any number but if autocompaction disabled then you can see many pending task and no running task on nodetool compactionstats.